# Easy way to access child components values from parent component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Lets say I have a structure like below:

```
<my-table>
    <my-row>
        <my-col>Value 1</my-col>
        <my-col>Value 2</my-col>
    </my-row>
    <my-row>
        <my-col>Value 3</my-col>
        <my-col>Value 4</my-col>
    </my-row>
</my-table>
```

Now, after page render I would like to have a variable in my-table component with structure like that:

```
[
  ['Value 1', 'Value 2'],
  ['Value 3', 'Value 4']
]
```

And any changes which I do on this variable (sorting, filtering etc.) must be dynamically rendered.

How to achieve this?

**//edit**
**I cannot do this with nested *ngFor because I want to have other components inside my-col for example bootstrap progress bars etc.**

Regards

Comment: See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html and perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to pass array of `cols` to each `row`, i.e.
`my-table` component template would be

```
<my-row ng-repeat="row in rows" cols="row" />
```

where `rows` is your array of arrays.
And `my-row` component template would be somethings like

```
<my-col ng-repeat="col in cols" />
```

And `cols: '='` is two-way binding from `my-table` to `my-row`.

Comment: This solution does not fit to me because I may want to use another components (progress bars, etc.) as col value

Comment: @MichalBialek I think thing you want to have now could be achieved with attribute directives, where `my-col` from code above, could be `div` with attribute for your component (e.g. field from object in array)

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with nested *ngFor, the first to get each row and the second one to get the columns in every row:

```
<my-table>
   <my-row *ngFor="let row of arr">
       <my-col *ngFor="let column of row">{{ column }}</my-col>
   </my-row>
</my-table>
```

Comment: as I said I cannot do this because I want to have a other components inside <my-col>